# Error is not triggering on url session using combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

```
enum FailureReason : Error {
  case sessionFailed(error: URLError)
  case decodingFailed
  case other(Error)
}
```

the custom error enum

```
 private func performOperation<T: Decodable>(requestUrl: URLRequest, responseType: T.Type)->AnyPublisher<T, FailureReason>
   {
return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: requestUrl)
          .map(\.data)
          .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
          .mapError({ error -> FailureReason in
            switch error {
            case is Swift.DecodingError:
              return .decodingFailed
            case let urlError as URLError:
              return .sessionFailed(error: urlError)
            default:
              return .other(error)
            }
          })
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   
}
```

this is how my urlsession publisher looks like

```
func validateLogin(username : String , password :String) {
    
    let url = "\(Constants.baseUrl)api/v1/auth/login/"
    let htppbodyRequest = EmailLogin(username: username, password: password)
    let httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(htppbodyRequest)
    
   cancellable = webservice.apiRequest(url: URL(string: url)!, resultType: User.self, httpMethodType: .post, requestBody: httpBody)
             .map{ $0 }
             .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
             .sink(receiveCompletion: {
                print("Received completion: \($0).")
             }, receiveValue: { (user) in
                  print("user name is :\(user)")
                  self.subject.send(user)
            })
```

User is the decodable struct. Even if i enter invalid username and password the Received completion of sink prints finished error is never thrown.
Subject is a passthroughSubject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a misunderstanding regarding when a `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` should fail with an error. A data task only fails with an error in case there is a network error (such as no internet connection, SSL error, etc).

Inputting an incorrect username or password is not a network error and hence will not result in the data task throwing an error. Depending on your backend implementation, it might result in an error status code (not in the 200..<300 range) and an error response in the body of the request.

To check the status code of the `HTTPURLResponse` and throw an error in case it's incorrect, you can use `tryMap` on the `dataTaskPublisher`.

Here's how you can define convenience methods on `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` that handle the status code of the `HTTPURLResponse` and throw an error in case it's incorrect.

```
enum NetworkingError: Error {
    case decoding(DecodingError)
    case incorrectStatusCode(Int)
    case network(URLError)
    case nonHTTPResponse
    case unknown(Error)
}

extension Publisher {
    func mapErrorToNetworkingError() -> AnyPublisher<Output, NetworkingError> {
        mapError { error -> NetworkingError in
            switch error {
            case let decodingError as DecodingError:
                return .decoding(decodingError)
            case let networkingError as NetworkingError:
                return networkingError
            case let urlError as URLError:
                return .network(urlError)
            default:
                return .unknown(error)
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
    func emptyBodyResponsePublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Void, NetworkingError> {
        httpResponseValidator()
        .map { _ in Void() }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
    func httpResponseValidator() -> AnyPublisher<Output, NetworkingError> {
        tryMap { data, response in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw NetworkingError.nonHTTPResponse }
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            guard (200..<300).contains(statusCode) else { throw NetworkingError.incorrectStatusCode(statusCode) }
            return (data, httpResponse)
        }
        .mapErrorToNetworkingError()
    }

    func httpResponseValidatorDataPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Data, NetworkingError> {
        httpResponseValidator()
        .map(\.data)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func jsonDecodingPublisher<T:Decodable>(type: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, NetworkingError> {
        httpResponseValidatorDataPublisher()
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .mapErrorToNetworkingError()
    }
}
```

And then you can simplify your `performOperation` function as below and it will throw an error in case the status code of the response is not in the expected range.

```
private func performOperation<T: Decodable>(requestUrl: URLRequest, responseType: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, NetworkingError> {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: requestUrl)
        .jsonDecodingPublisher(type: T.self)
}
```

Comment: How can I use this code sir. I couldn't use.
private func performOperation<T: Decodable>(requestUrl: URLRequest, responseType: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, NetworkingError> {  }