# wrong url is not triggering error using combine

Tags: swift, error-handling, combine

I am using the code here. But I couldn't figure out how to use the code here.

**Stack Overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126447/error-is-not-triggering-on-url-session-using-combine)**

How can I run this function with combine?
How can I run a function with return type `AnyPublisher<T, NetworkingError>` with combine and catch errors.
my apikey is faulty and i want to catch this error.

**Function:**

```
private func performOperation<T: Decodable>(requestUrl: URLRequest, responseType: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, NetworkingError> {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: requestUrl)
            .jsonDecodingPublisher(type: T.self)
    }
```

**My Code:**

```
class MovieService {
    
    private let baseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie"
    private let apiKey = "594b8eb4999a8b44ad5136ee3ed1ebdb31"
    private let language = "language=en-US"
    var anyCancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    init() { }
    
    func loadAllMovie(categoryType: CategoryType, page: Int) -> Future<Movie, Error> {
        
        
        if let url = URL(string: baseURL + "/" + categoryType.rawValue + "?" + "api_key=" + apiKey + "&" + language + "&" + "page=" + "\(page)") {
            
            let foo = performOperation(requestUrl: URLRequest(url: url), responseType: Movie.self)
            foo
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink { error in
                    switch error {
                        
                    case .finished:
                        print("end")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                } receiveValue: { movie in
                    print(movie)
                }
                .store(in: &anyCancellable)
            
        } else {
            print("url sıkıntılı")
        }
        
        
        
        if let data = getData(from: baseURL, categoryType: categoryType, page: page) {
            do {
                
                let bookDecoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Movie.self, from: data)
                
                return Future { promixe in
                    promixe(.success(bookDecoder))
                }
            }catch {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                debugPrint("errrrr: \(error)")
                print("olmadı")
            }
        }
        return Future{ _ in }
    }
    
    private func performOperation<T: Decodable>(requestUrl: URLRequest, responseType: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, NetworkingError> {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: requestUrl)
            .jsonDecodingPublisher(type: T.self)
    }
    
    private func getData(from urlString: String, categoryType: CategoryType, page: Int) -> Data? {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString + "/" + categoryType.rawValue + "?" + "api_key=" + apiKey + "&" + language + "&" + "page=" + "\(page)") else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load URL from provided string.")
        }
        
        do {
            return try Data(contentsOf: url)
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Couldn't load data from URL:\n\(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

enum NetworkingError: Error {
    case decoding(DecodingError)
    case incorrectStatusCode(Int)
    case network(URLError)
    case nonHTTPResponse
    case unknown(Error)
}

extension Publisher {
    func mapErrorToNetworkingError() -> AnyPublisher<Output, NetworkingError> {
        mapError { error -> NetworkingError in
            switch error {
            case let decodingError as DecodingError:
                return .decoding(decodingError)
            case let networkingError as NetworkingError:
                return networkingError
            case let urlError as URLError:
                return .network(urlError)
            default:
                return .unknown(error)
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
    func emptyBodyResponsePublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Void, NetworkingError> {
        httpResponseValidator()
            .map { _ in Void() }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
    func httpResponseValidator() -> AnyPublisher<Output, NetworkingError> {
        tryMap { data, response in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw NetworkingError.nonHTTPResponse }
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            guard (200..<300).contains(statusCode) else { throw NetworkingError.incorrectStatusCode(statusCode) }
            return (data, httpResponse)
        }
        .mapErrorToNetworkingError()
    }
    
    func httpResponseValidatorDataPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Data, NetworkingError> {
        httpResponseValidator()
            .map(\.data)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func jsonDecodingPublisher<T:Decodable>(type: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<T, NetworkingError> {
        httpResponseValidatorDataPublisher()
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .mapErrorToNetworkingError()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  You can call `performOperation` and it will return a publisher.  You would then subscribe to that publisher to "run" it.  Can you try to clarify where you are having trouble?